# Compile .ui file (to .cpp and .h file) without full build in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

It's kinda surprising, but Qt seems to work much better with Visual Studio (with Qt add-on) than their own IDE, QtCreator.

In Visual Studio, right clicking an UI file in project view allows you to compile it, producing `ui_something.h`:

[image: image description]

In QtCreator, I see no obvious way to build it. There is no button for it. Actually, there's a button in Build menu:

[image: image description]

It compiles the project, while `ui_main.h` remains unchanged. I actually don't even know, how did I manage to generate the old `ui_main.h`, now outdated since I edited the form. There just seems no way, maybe apart from a command line solution.

Answer (score 2):

In case this doesn't get a fully qualified answer, I'll just leave here that you can do it manually in command line:

```
uic main.ui>ui_main.h
```

`uic` prints the output on stdout, so you need to use `>` operator to save output in a file.